# Cleaning up holes in MultiPolygon using QGIS

Tags: polygon, geojson, geometry, multi-polygon, holes

This is a screencap of my map in QGIS:

[image]

Those orange bits in the middle of each section are actually holes in the GeoJSON file and I can't make them go away. I've tried using the "Vertex tool" to select the vertices and delete them with "Delete ring" but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I cover them?

[Link to the data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jtQ9tG0IdAY3W_7eRxkoL9p3pWnDdErp/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Probably your features contain geomtry errors. Try Geometry checker plugin. For more detailed answer, it would be good if you could share your data.

Comment: Fair enough.  [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O-6kpdqdvKYuBO-09BtQEaI4jMZPLvbq/view?usp=sharing) is a Google Drive link to download the data in question.

Comment: You question was closed because it contained several questions - you should edit it to comply with the rules so that it can be reopened. Otherwise, no one can post an answer.

Comment: You provided a link to the QGIS project file (.qgz).  It doesn't contain any data, only links to the data and since we don't have the data, those links don't work.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jtQ9tG0IdAY3W_7eRxkoL9p3pWnDdErp/view?usp=sharing) is the Google Drive link with the data.  That should be a GeoJSON file.

Comment: I have looked at your data, and there only one multipart polygon (it's the yellowish-green one from your screenshot). You can get rid of those small parts if you select them with the vertex tool and simply press the `Delete` Key. If you have problems with the merge function, you should try the Repair Geometries tool from the Processing toolbox.

Comment: Well that was a simple fix.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: @CezarB, please put your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at your data, and there is only one multipart polygon (*it's the yellowish-green one from your screenshot*).
You can get rid of those small parts if you select them with the vertex tool and simply press the `Delete` Key.
If you have problems with the merge function, you should try the Repair Geometries tool from the Processing toolbox.