# Merging features returns error message using QGIS

Tags: merge, features

[This is a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O-6kpdqdvKYuBO-09BtQEaI4jMZPLvbq/view?usp=sharing) to the data I'm using in QGIS.

In this map, there is a layer comprised of municipalities, each of which is a feature of that layer.  I've been selecting the municipalities I want from the orange layer underneath all of these larger sections, exporting the selected features as a GeoJSON file, making that file its own layer, and then merging the features of that layer.

However, sometimes, when I try to merge the features, I get the error message:

> Merge failed: An error occurred during the merge operation.

How do I fix/troubleshoot this?

The exact steps I took were:

1. I left-click the layer in question in the "layers" panel.
2. I go into "Edit" mode.
3. I select two features in that layer that I want to merge.
4. I select Edit --> Merge Selected Features. Then the error message I just mentioned comes up.

Comment: You didn't link any data. Just the actual QGIS project file. QGIS is different from, say, CAD, as a QGIS file doesn't store any data. Just links to data sources.

Comment: This question is a duplicate to this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/414739/cleaning-up-holes-in-map-and-features-wont-merge-using-qgis  - please update (edit) your original question, don't post the same question twice.

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jtQ9tG0IdAY3W_7eRxkoL9p3pWnDdErp/view?usp=sharing) is the link to the GeoJSON file.

Comment: What are the precise and detailed steps that lead to you seeing this error message?

Comment: 1. I left-click the layer in question in the "layers" panel.  2. I select two features in that layer that I want to merge.  3. I select Edit --> Merge Selected Features.  Then the error message I just mentioned comes up.

Comment: Please [EDIT] the question in response to requests for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The GeoJSON is a multipolygon, meaning there is nothing to merge, as all the polygons are already part of the same feature.

First use the [Multipart to Singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#multipart-to-singleparts) tool, before merging the selected features.

Though, I suspect using the [Dissolve](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#dissolve) tool will give your desired result.